# Android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after importing jar. Wrong jar?

Tags: java, android, jar, runtime-error

After I've imported jar file into Android project and ran it, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` At first I thought that I'm doing something wrong while importing it, but then I tryed to import jar that I've from some online class and it worked! So here is my question:

**Is there any specific way of creating jar files for Android project?**

I've to point out that first jar is created from Java class that I wrote some time ago. This jar works without problems in another java app. The jar was created using Eclipse Kepler.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution shoved up to be pretty simple. Currently I'm using **Java 1.7** to create my jar files, but **Android accepts** only jars that were created with **Java 1.6**. So the problem is caused probably by some incompatibility in bytecode and therefore you need to force compiler to use Java 1.6.

If you're using Eclipse, go to `Project properties > Java compiler` and select `Compiler compliance level: 1.6` Save changes and rebuild your project. You're ready to export "working" jar :)